# Is there an easy way to calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2x\ \cos^4x\ dx $?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2x\ \cos^4x\ dx  $$

by hand. The standard substitution $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ is too difficult.
 Multiple integration by parts together with clever manipulations can give the result.

But it would be nice to have an easier method, perhaps one single substitution or some useful formulas for trigonometric powers.

Comment: Maybe use $\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x$. Then try a substitution.

Comment: Then I get the integrals over $cos^4x$ and $cos^6x$.

Comment: Then use $\cos(x)^2=1/2+1/2*\cos(2x)$

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), particularly the chapter dealing with their connection to [beta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $\sin x \cos x =\frac {\sin 2x}{2}$ and $\cos^2 x=\frac {1+\cos 2x}2$

Then $\sin^2 2x = \frac {1-\cos 4x}{2}$ and you can find a suitable formula for $\cos 2x \cos 4x$.

This way you can reduce the integral from the sixth power of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ combined to a trigonometric function of $6x$ using standard trig identities. Then it is easy to integrate.

Comment: How can I manipulate $cos2x\ cos4x$, so that it is easy to integrate ?

Comment: @Peter $\cos (A+B)=\cos A\cos B - \sin A\sin B$ and $\cos (A-B)=\cos A\cos B + \sin A \sin B$. If you add these and divide by $2$ to get $\cos A \cos B=\frac {\cos (A+B)+\cos (A-B)}2$

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice trick. By symmetry, we have:
$$ I = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2\theta\cos^4\theta\,d\theta = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^4\theta\cos^2\theta\,d\theta $$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta\,(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2(2\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2\theta\,d\theta=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{8}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: Nice, I was just typing the same, but was too slow :)

Comment: Could you please justify the first line ? I do not quite see the symmetries.

Comment: The graphs of $\sin^2 (\theta) \cos^4 (\theta)$ and $\sin^4 (\theta) \cos^2 (\theta)$ (on $[0,\pi/2]$) are symmetric over the line $x = \pi/4$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$ and the binomial theorem.

Even further to simplify the algebra a bit initially you can use $$\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$$